# How to create a transparent difference (additive?) layer from 2 solid layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, mask, blend-modes

I'm very new to graphic design in general, so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terms, sorry about that. I have two solid images (A & B) and I want to extract the difference between the two to a seperate image (C). See this example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I create the last image using the first two in Photoshop? (CS6) Can I somehow subtract image A from image B to create image C?

I tried using blend modes but I never was able to end up with a *transparent* image. I also tried using layer masks but then the color wouldn't work out as nicely as in the example.

Comment: Do your images have the black background?

Comment: @Scott yes, both have a solid black background.

Comment: Okay.. next question... did you add the blur? Or *must* you work with that already blurred image?

Comment: The *easiest* solution would be to remove or mask the black in A and then reapply a blur to it.

Comment: @Scott no I did not add the blur. The circles are just an example for my problem which is a little more complex, but the idea is the same. I basically have an image which has some added effects (such as glow and blur), this is image B from my example. I recreated the image precisely in Photoshop except for the glow and blur, image A. I am now asking if there is a Photoshop technique which allows me to extract the difference between the two images to a new layer, so I can use the glow and blur as a sort of additive layer.

Comment: There are techniques, but nothing automated that I'm aware of. Which technique works is really dependent upon the *actual* artwork. I'm afraid the samples you've posted would lead to very rudimentary steps that wouldn't really work for artwork of a more complex nature. Perhaps I'm incorrect though and someone has a technique better than what I can think of.